# I can't start spamassassin service

Tags: 14.04, mail

I have installed and configured spammassassin in my system(14.04) using this [tutor](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-setup-spamassassin-on-ubuntu-12-04). 
When I start a service using,

```
service spamassassin start
```

am getting response as,

```
Starting SpamAssassin Mail Filter Daemon: server socket setup failed, retry 1: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [::1]:783: Cannot assign requested address
server socket setup failed, retry 2: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 3: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 4: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 5: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 6: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 7: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 8: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
server socket setup failed, retry 9: spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
spamd: could not create IO::Socket::INET6 socket on [127.0.0.1]:783: Address already in use
```

I have tried,

```
netstat -lptn
```

it's showing,

[image]

there is process running with 127.0.1.1:783

also tried,

```
sudo netstat -lepnt
```

am getting,

[image]

here too not showing any process run with  127.0.1.1:783

Please tell me where the problem cause ?

Comment: See answer below, but you should probably do `sudo service spamassassin start`.

Comment: @Jos I did it friend sudo service spamassassin start it's not working...

Comment: Is there anything useful in /var/log/spamassassin?

Comment: @Jos nothing shown there...

Comment: At this point, it would be more or less guessing what is wrong. Did you follow all the steps from [this article](http://www.geoffstratton.com/2013/06/mail-server-spamassassin/) carefully? Or something like it?

Comment: @Jos I followed [this blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-setup-spamassassin-on-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: I have IPv6 disabled via sysctl.conf so why the INET6 error? "sudo netstat -lptn | grep 783" returns nothing.

Comment: Aktive Internetverbindungen (Nur Server)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State User Inode PID/Program name
tcp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 0 12469 1224/dnsmasq tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:631 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 0 14860089 4815/cupsd tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:17500 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1000 21346 2337/dropbox tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:445 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 0 11297 554/smbd tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:139 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 0 11298 554/smbd tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:10000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 0 21466 2696/perl tcp6 0 0 :::3128 :::* LISTEN 0 14863578 1030/squid3 tcp6 0 0 :::445 :::* LISTEN 0 11295 554/smbd tcp6 0 0 :::139 :::* LISTEN 0

Comment: maybe you have deactivated ipv6, check with: ip addr show | grep inet6

Comment: @Philipp yes I have deactivated ipv6 for Hadoop, is that is a problem?

Comment: Run spamd in ipv4 only mode by adding "-4" to the OPTIONS="" string in /etc/default/spamassassin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run `sudo netstat -lptn | grep 783` and get the PID (right most side of the output - some thing like 2332/spamd.pid ) of the program that uses 783 port. Then kill that program with `sudo kill -9 PID`.
Then start the spamassasin

`service spamassassin start`

If you still get the INET6 socket error, try running spamd without IPv6 support (assuming you don't need it).

```
sudo nano /etc/default/spamassassin
```

Add -4 to your OPTIONS line

```
spamd --help

...
-4, --ipv4-only, --ipv4           Use IPv4 where applicable, disables IPv6
...
```

Otherwise, troubleshoot your IPv6 config.

Comment: when i run, netstat -lptn | grep 783
there is no process showing...

Comment: try it with sudo netstat

Comment: 127.0.1.1:53 & 631 are running..

Comment: i tried both sudo netstat & netstat -lptn, 783 not showing..

Comment: can you post the output of `sudo netstat -lepnt`

Comment: I posted in my question...

Comment: Anything useful from `sudo ps -aux | grep spam` ? - that should at least show any PIDs that relate to it

Comment: @Rob Cowell, i got this o/p for 'sudo ps -aux | grep spam', 
'arul     11798  0.0  0.0  15940   916 pts/0    S+   09:43   0:00 grep --color=auto spam'

Comment: @AJ it is the grep process. Try to restart the service service spamassassin restart.

Comment: @Rob Cowell, am getting the same response when I start spamassassin..

Comment: -4 did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Check if ipv6 is enabled

```
sysctl -a|grep disable_ipv6
```

If it isn't enable it or disable ipv6 in spamassassin as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The answers here did not help me at all. I found that the problem went away, without disabling IPv6, by editing `/etc/default/spamassassin` and adding a user for `spamd`, as described [here](http://www.geoffstratton.com/spamassassin-ubuntu). The essential steps described in that page are:

1) `sudo apt-get install spamassassin spamc`

2) `sudo adduser spamd --disabled-login`

3) Edit `/etc/default/spamassassin` to include the following:

```
ENABLED=1
SPAMD_HOME="/home/spamd/"
OPTIONS="--create-prefs --max-children 5 --username spamd --helper-home-dir ${SPAMD_HOME} -s ${SPAMD_HOME}spamd.log"
PIDFILE="${SPAMD_HOME}spamd.pid"
CRON=1
```

4) Edit `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf` to set up some anti-spam rules, e.g.,

```
rewrite_header Subject ***** SPAM *****
report_safe             0
required_score          5.0
use_bayes               1
use_bayes_rules         1
bayes_auto_learn        1
```

5) `sudo service spamassassin start`

One more step is described, to update `postfix`, which was not needed in my case. I think the core of the issue is step 2 and then adding `--username spamd` in the `OPTIONS` of `/etc/default/spamassassin`

Answer (score 0):

### Update: how to start the spamassassin service with Ubuntu 20.10

Install `spamassassin` (and also `spamc` and `sa-compile`):

```
% sudo apt install spamassassin
```

Spamassassin can be run in the foreground with `spamassassin` and in the background as a daemon with `spamd -d`.

The installation creates a non login user `debian-spamd`.

[Why a dedicated user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29159/why-is-it-recommended-to-create-a-group-and-user-for-some-applications)

```
% grep spamd /etc/passwd
debian-spamd:x:131:136::/var/lib/spamassassin:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Do not create user `spamd`!

Make a startup item:

```
% sudo systemctl enable spamassassin  
Synchronizing state of spamassassin.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable spamassassin
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/spamassassin.service → /lib/systemd/system/spamassassin.service.
```

Check the configuration:

```
% cat /lib/systemd/system/spamassassin.service
[Unit]
Description=Perl-based spam filter using text analysis
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/spamd.pid
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/spamassassin
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid $OPTIONS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My best guess for configuration file `/etc/default/spamassassin` is:

```
OPTIONS="--debug --create-prefs --username=debian-spamd --max-children=5 --username=debian-spamd --helper-home-dir --syslog=/var/log/spamd.log"
```

See `man spamd` for all options.

Start service without restarting the computer:

```
% sudo systemctl start spamassassin
```

or

```
% sudo service spamassassin start
```

Restart service after configuration change without restarting the computer:

```
% sudo service spamassassin restart
```

Check status:

```
% sudo service spamassassin status 
● spamassassin.service - Perl-based spam filter using text analysis
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/spamassassin.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-06-21 00:47:10 WEST; 1s ago
    Process: 56524 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 56529 (spamd)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 19035)
     Memory: 98.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/spamassassin.service
             ├─56529 /usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid --debug --create-prefs --max-children=5 --username=debian-spa>
             ├─56530 spamd child
             └─56531 spamd child
```

Check running options:

```
% ps -ef|grep spamd              
root       56529       1  0 00:47 ?        00:00:01 /usr/bin/perl -T -w /usr/sbin/spamd -d --pidfile=/run/spamd.pid --debug --create-prefs --max-children=5 --username=debian-spamd --helper-home-dir=/var/lib/spamassassin --syslog=/var/lib/spamassasin/spamd.log
debian-+   56530   56529  0 00:47 ?        00:00:00 spamd child
debian-+   56531   56529  0 00:47 ?        00:00:00 spamd child
```

where `debian-+` is a shorthand for `debian-spamd` (too long for `ps`).

Check PID:

```
% cat /run/spamd.pid
56529
```

Check that `spamd` is listening on the network:

```
% sudo netstat -nlp|grep 56529
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:783     0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN      
56529/perl           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:783        :::*    LISTEN      
56529/perl
```

Given default port number 783, `sudo netstat -nlp|grep 783` will return the same information independently of the PID.

[spamd can be used with a mail server](https://www.binarytides.com/install-spamassassin-with-postfix-dovecot/) but it can also be used directly in the command line. After `spamc`, type some text, exit with `Control-D`, this yields a report.

The same report can be obtained with `spamassassin`.

`spamd` itself can be launched in the command line.

In `/etc/default/spamassassin`, ENABLE, PIDFILE, CRON have no effect.  With CRON = 1, I see no cron job:

```
% sudo crontab -u debian-spamd -l
no crontab for debian-spamd

% sudo crontab -u root -l        
no crontab for root
```

Other configuration file: `/etc/init.d/spamassassin`.

Do not confuse the spamassassin **service** configuration (discussed so far) with the spamassassin configuration (how to detect spam).  The latter is explained in `man spamassassin`, in particular the configuration file names.